# React Native Expo CLI Import .ttf Fonts

Tags: react-native

Trying to import .ttf for font in expo cli.
I also have splash screen. I wanna show the splash screen until the font loads.

*Font: Josefin Sans.*
*"expo": "~45.0.0"*

I took reference from following links but nothing works:

1. Using Custom Fonts: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/
2. Splash Screen: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/

> Code (App.js)

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

import { Text } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import Header from "./components/Header.component";
import styles from "./styles/appStyle";

import * as Font from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

const App = () => {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // Pre-load fonts
        await Font.loadAsync({
          "JosefinSans-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf"),
        });
        // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
        // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
        <Header />
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
        <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="#05060B" />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

> Error

```js
Android Bundling failed 12ms
Unable to resolve module ./assets/fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf from C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\App.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * JosefinSans-Regular.ttf
  * assets\fonts\JosefinSans-Regular.ttf\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  18 |         // Pre-load fonts
  19 |         await Font.loadAsync({
> 20 |           "JosefinSans-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf"),
     |                                           ^
  21 |         });
  22 |         // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading 
  23 |         // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
```

**File Structure:
[Snap.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLrsQ.png)**

Comment: If you're using Google fonts (which I think you are), Expo already has a library for that. See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo-google-fonts/josefin-sans

Comment: I did that too but instead of `expo install @expo-google-fonts/josefin-sans expo-font` I did `expo install @expo-google-fonts/JosefinSans expo-font` when I did it first. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Answer

**expo install @expo-google-fonts/josefin-sans expo-font**

And the code looks like this.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

import { Text } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import Header from "./components/Header.component";
import styles from "./styles/appStyle";

import * as Font from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

import {
  useFonts,
  JosefinSans_100Thin,
  JosefinSans_200ExtraLight,
  JosefinSans_300Light,
  JosefinSans_400Regular,
  JosefinSans_500Medium,
  JosefinSans_600SemiBold,
  JosefinSans_700Bold,
  JosefinSans_100Thin_Italic,
  JosefinSans_200ExtraLight_Italic,
  JosefinSans_300Light_Italic,
  JosefinSans_400Regular_Italic,
  JosefinSans_500Medium_Italic,
  JosefinSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
  JosefinSans_700Bold_Italic,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/josefin-sans";

const App = () => {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    JosefinSans_100Thin,
    JosefinSans_200ExtraLight,
    JosefinSans_300Light,
    JosefinSans_400Regular,
    JosefinSans_500Medium,
    JosefinSans_600SemiBold,
    JosefinSans_700Bold,
    JosefinSans_100Thin_Italic,
    JosefinSans_200ExtraLight_Italic,
    JosefinSans_300Light_Italic,
    JosefinSans_400Regular_Italic,
    JosefinSans_500Medium_Italic,
    JosefinSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
    JosefinSans_700Bold_Italic,
  });

const prepare = async () => {
    try {
      // Pre-load fonts
      await Font.loadAsync(fontsLoaded)
        .then(() => {
          setAppIsReady(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {});
      // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
      // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
      // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
        <Header />
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
        <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="#05060B" />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```